# Quarkus Native additional build args with Gradle

Tags: gradle, quarkus, quarkus-native

Trying to solve an issue with Proxy classes + native mode with Quarkus, and hitting a roadblock.

The docs outlining the tips for solving the issue don't specify how to add the additional build args with Gradle....

Reference docs: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#managing-proxy-classes

The odd point being I found the following issue outlining an addition for Gradle, but no mention on the docs, and the command the issue recommends doesn't seem to work either (`--additional-build-args`)

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3484

How does one pass the args to Graal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to is configure `application.properties` with all the additional setting you need.

For example you could have something like:

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:IncludeResources=.*\\.jks,-H:EnableURLProtocols=http\\,https
```

Comment: Ah, see that now in the linked guide. Thanks